# h:inputFile null pointer exception

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I am learning to use JSF 2.2 and the upload file tag.

So I created a basis xhtml file to upload a file in a bean:

```html
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{fileupload.uploadedFile}" />

    <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{fileupload.saveFile}" />
</h:form>
```

Here is the associated backing-bean :

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Fileupload {

    private Part uploadedFile; // getters + setters

    private String folder = "c:\\files";

    public void saveFile(){
        try (InputStream input = uploadedFile.getInputStream()) { // <-- Nullpointer here
            String fileName = uploadedFile.getSubmittedFileName();

            Files.copy(input, new File(folder, fileName).toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I submit the form i have this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.pro.beans.Fileupload.saveFile(Fileupload.java:30)
```

---

So my guess is that the `uploadFile` mutable is not set by the xhtml and so when I click on the button I got a `NullpointerException`, but I do understand why is it not set cause for me it is conform to all the tutorial I saw.

Comment: Instead of posting a whole stack trace as if you have no clue what exactly a NullPointerException is (and thus risking your question to be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384), can you please just tell which variable exactly is null where your code didn't expect that?

Comment: Hi, thx for your feedback I edited my question.

Comment: Hi, BalusC is right, you should be more explicit. Effectively your question is very much related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded. Read the code parts after '3', especially the **_'Save it, now'_** part and the last paragraph before the 'PrimeFaces 8.x' part.

Comment: My question is a duplication from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342502/jsf-2-2-file-upload-return-java-lang-nullpointerexception It solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

I there,

```
public Part getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(Part file) {
    this.file = file;
}
```