# Assign value to an hidden text input with JS

Tags: javascript, jsf

i'm a newbie of JavaScript.

I have that :

HTML:

```
<form>
<t:inputFileUpload required="true" id="upload" onchange="uploadOnChange()" />
<input id="filename" type="hidden" />
<h:commandButton class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload"
            action="#{controller.upload}" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
function uploadOnChange() {

document.getElementById('upload').onchange = name;

var filename = name;
var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);

document.getElementById('filename').value = filename;
}
</script>
```

All I want to do is get through a inputFileUpload, to browse my directory, the filename that i've selected, and pass this name as a string to jsf controller.

Does anyone can help me?

EDIT :

If I add to my form `enctype="multipart/form-data` seems that the controller method "upload" does nothing.

Comment: This doesn't seem right: `document.getElementById('upload').onchange = name;`

Comment: [about uploading with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file) maybe this helps you to close the question.

Comment: Are you new to JSF too? JSF needs an `<h:form>` instead of a `<form>` to work properly. And the `t:inputFileUpload` will pass on the filename... no need to do that in a separate field... I think you are trying to solve another problem in the wrong way

Comment: yes i'm new to jsf too, i'm in high school :)... if I use <h:form> doesn't work anyway.

Comment: I've tried to do that:                                                                                                     I've put in form `multipart/form-data` and than in my controller i've tried to do `file.getfileName()` but it doesn't work... so i was searchng for another way...

Comment: `t:inputFileUpload` is from tomahawk, an old and not really supported library. If you are actually using jsf-2.2, use the `h:inputFile`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677397/how-to-upload-file-using-jsf-2-2-hinputfile-where-is-the-saved-file. What tutorial are you using?

Comment: I'm using various answered question on stackoverflow

Comment: But take a good look at the dates of the questions!!! And look at 'versions' specified in them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `<t:inputFileUpload>` has a `value` attribute, I'd change the code to something like this:

```js
function uploadOnChange() {
  var filename = document.getElementById('upload').value;
  var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
  if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
    document.getElementById('filename').value = filename;
  }
  console.log('Value hidden input: ' + document.getElementById('filename').value);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" required="true" id="upload" onchange="uploadOnChange()" />
<input id="filename" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: what value i've to add to inputFileUpload ? i need that only to select the file that i want the name .... i'm very sorry,  i'm very inexpert.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add it, it should be there, or maybe with another name. You should be able to get the filename from `inputFileUpload` in some way.

Comment: @alex Added a runnable snippet with a standard HTML file upload control as an example.

Comment: thank you very much, but can i return filename value to my jsf controller class to use that string? I've assigned to hidden input value as `value="#{controller.file}"`

Comment: I'm a .NET developer, this is a JS question. You have to figure that out yourself or ask another question with the correct tags.

Comment: JSF is JavaServer Faces, right? Java is not JavaScript (ECMAScript). Part of the question is for JS, but how to read it on server-side is not.

Comment: @Arg0n: thanks for trying to help, but OP most likely has a different problem (http://xyproblem.info/) and is trying to solve a new/resulting problem in a wrong/complex. Nothing JS related to the real problem.