# Trinidad/ADF Faces, file upload, EOFException

Tags: jsf, file-upload, trinidad, eofexception

I use JSF 2.3 (Mojarra 2.3.3), Trinidad (2.2.1) and its file upload component (tr:inputFile) in a web.xml-version 3.1 on a Tomcat 8.5 server.

I get following exception and no valid uploaded file (i.e. the "value"-binded bean attribute remains null):

```
java.io.EOFException: null
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler._readLine(MultipartFormHandler.java:253) ~[trinidad-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler._readLine(MultipartFormHandler.java:237) ~[trinidad-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler._skipBoundary(MultipartFormHandler.java:223) ~[trinidad-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler.<init>(MultipartFormHandler.java:102) ~[trinidad-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler.<init>(MultipartFormHandler.java:75) ~[trinidad-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.upload.FileUploadConfiguratorImpl.beginRequest(FileUploadConfiguratorImpl.java:139) [trinidad-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl._startConfiguratorServiceRequest(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:763) [trinidad-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl.beginRequest(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:244) [trinidad-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:178) [trinidad-impl-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92) [trinidad-api-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
```

(Info: The JSF 1.2 version with Trinidad 1.2.14 with web.xml-version 2.5 on Tomcat 6 or a Weblogic 10 does not have this problem.)

While searching for a solution I found that this seems to affect not only my concrete situation, but also:

- ADF Faces (at least 12.x)
- Trinidad 2.1
- JSF 2.x in general
- Wildfly (10.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for an answer I developed a solution I want to share.

Use JSF's `<h:inputFile>` (since JSF 2.2) instead of `<tr:inputFile>`.
You may continue to use `<tr:form usesUpload="true">`, but see notes below.
In the backing bean you have to simply replace `org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.model.UploadedFile` with `javax.servlet.http.Part` and use `getSubmittedFileName()` instead of `getFileName()`.

With this, file upload already works, but the `EOFException` still occurs and is logged (but ignored internally).
To prevent the needed `TrinidadFilter` (configured in `web.xml`) from processing the file upload, add your own `javax.servlet.Filter` (most apps will already have one, I guess) and put in its `doFilter()`:

```
request.setAttribute("org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.upload.FileUploadUtils.PROCESSED", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Of course, your filter must be executed *before* the `TrinidadFilter`, so either use a broader filter-mapping or place it before TrinidadFilter in your `web.xml`.

Additional notes:

- When using `<tr:form>` the `<h:inputFile>` will output the wrong error/warning *"File upload component requires a form with an enctype of multipart/form-data"* via FacesMessage - but *not* for `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` Production.
  You may simply ignore it in development or use `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">` instead. But note: `<h:form>` is a naming container and `<tr:form>` is not, so addressing input elements differs (`hformId:inputId` instead of simple `inputId`)
- If your `<tr:inputFile>` is used inside a `<tr:panelFormLayout>`, put the `<h:inputFile>` inside a `<tr:panelLabelAndMessage>` and put the label there.
- CSS styling for `af|inputFile::content` must also be done for `input[type="file"]`.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27681292/5074004
- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274824?_sscc=t
- http://myfaces.10567.n7.nabble.com/Trinidad-File-upload-issue-td30231.html