# Unable to Export Excel File pragmatically from ADF application in Payara server using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, oracle-adf, payara

I am using the Apache POI library to download an excel file from my ADF Application in Payara server. Below is the exception message

```
java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler._skipBoundary(MultipartFormHandler.java:247)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler.<init>(MultipartFormHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler.<init>(MultipartFormHandler.java:75)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.upload.FileUploadConfiguratorImpl.beginRequest(FileUploadConfiguratorImpl.java:139)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl._startConfiguratorServiceRequest(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:746)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl.beginRequest(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:227)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:184)
at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:257)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Code is working in Weblogic Server.

other Details are

Jdeveloper 12.2.1.2.0

payara 5

weblogic 12C

Apache POI library 4.1 and tried with 3.9

Can anyone please suggest me if i have to add any lib in payara server or poi is not supported or anything?

Comment: Maybe same issue as this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752729/trinidad-adf-faces-file-upload-eofexception